# How to show the link inside the email in proper way

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email, ruby-on-rails-4

Please help to resolve this issue.Actually i want to send one confirmation link to email via ROR.The email has been sent but the url is not showing in proper way.

BELOW IS MY CODE SNIPPETS.

views/users/index.html

```
<h1>This is index page</h1>
        <center>
          <p>Enter data</p>
          <div class="option">
            <p><%= link_to "Click here to enter data",users_new_path %></p>
            <p><%= link_to "Display data",users_show_path%></p>
          </div>
        </center>
```

views/users/edit.html.erb

```
 <h1>Edit your data here</h1>
        <center>
          <%= form_for @user ,:url => {:action => "update",:id => params[:id]} do |f| %>
              <div class="div_reg">
                <p>
                  <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u" >username </label>&nbsp;
                  <%= f.text_field:name,placeholder:"Enter your user name" %>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u" >Email </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <%= f.text_field:email,placeholder:"enter your email" %>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u" >Password </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <%= f.password_field:password,placeholder:"Enter your password" %>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u" >Password </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <%= f.password_field  :password_confirmation %>
                </p>
                <center>
                  <%= f.submit "Update",:class => 'btn-custom' %>
                </center>
                <div class="back_btn">
                  <a href="/users/index"><button type="button" class="btn-custom " style="cursor:pointer;">Back</button></a>
                </div>
              </div>
          <% end %>
        </center>
        <% if @user.errors.any? %>
            <ul class="Signup_Errors">
              <% for message_error in @user.errors.full_messages %>
                  <li><%= message_error %></li>
              <% end %>
            </ul>
        <% end %>
```

views/users/show.html.erb

```
<h1>Show your data</h1>
<center>
  <ul>
    <% @user.each do |t| %>
        <li>
          <%= t.name %> |
          <%= t.email %> |
          <%= t.password%> |
          <%= t.created_at %>
          <%= link_to "edit",users_edit_path(:id => t.id) %>&nbsp;&nbsp;||&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= link_to "Reset Password",users_reset_path(:id => t.id) %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  <div class="back_btn">
    <a href="/users/index"><button type="button" class="btn-custom " style="cursor:pointer;">Back</button></a>
  </div>
</center>
```

controller/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end
  def new
    @user=User.new
  end
  def create
    @user=User.new(users_param);
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice]="You signed up successfully"
      flash[:color]="valid"
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
      flash[:alert]="You have not signed up successfully"
      flash[:color]="invalid"
      redirect_to :action => 'new'
    end
  end
  def show
    @user=User.all
  end
  def edit
    @user=User.new
  end
  def update
    flash[:notice]=params[:id]
    @user=User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(update_params)
      flash[:notice]="Your data is updated succesfully"
      flash[:color]="valid"
      redirect_to :action => 'show'
    else
      flash[:alert]="Your data could not update,Please check it..!!"
      flash[:color]="invalid"
      redirect_to :action => 'edit'
    end
  end
  def reset
    @user=User.new
  end
  def emailsend
    @user=User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.email== params[:user][:email]
      UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
      flash[:notice]="Check your email to reset the password"
      flash[:color]="valid"
      redirect_to :action => 'reset'
    else
      flash[:notice]="Check your valid email or your email is not found"
      flash[:color]="invalid"
      redirect_to :action => 'show'
    end
  end
  def resetpass
    @user=User.new
  end
  def passres
    @user=User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])
    if @user.update_attributes(updates_password)
      flash[:notice]="Your password id updated succefully"
      flash[:color]="valid"
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
      flash[:alert]="Your data could not update..Please check it..!!"
      flash[:color]="invalid"
      redirect_to :action => 'show'
    end
  end
  private
  def users_param
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,:password_confirmation)
  end
  def update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name,:email,:password,:password_confirmation)
  end
  def updates_password
    params.require(:user).permit(:email,:password,:password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

users_mailer/registration_confirmation.text.erb

```
<%= @user.name %>
Thank you for registering!
Edit Your Password <%= link_to "Click Here",users_resetpass_url( :host => "localhost:3000") %>
```

mailers/user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "w5call.w5rtc@gmail.com"
  def registration_confirmation(user)
    @user = user
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Registered")
  end
end
```

config/initializer/setup_mail.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => 587,
    :domain               => "gmail.com",
    :user_name            => "w5call.w5rtc@gmail.com",
    :password             => "w5rtc123@",
    :authentication       => "plain",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "localhost:3000"
```

Inside the email inbox it is showing like the below format.

```
bapi
Thank you for registering!
Edit Your Password <a href="http://localhost:3000/users/resetpass">Click Here</a>
```

But I want only "Click Here" to be shown and when user clicks on that text it should redirect to given link(Change Password).

Please help me to edit this and run it successfully.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have only provided a text template for your e-mail, and text files (since they're not HTML) can't contain HTML links.

You should provide another template `registration_confirmation.text.html.erb` (or rename your current template)

From the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html):

> The `mail` method, if not passed a block, will inspect your views and
>   send all the views with the same name as the method, so the above
>   action would send the `welcome.text.erb` view file as well as the
>   `welcome.text.html.erb` view file in a `multipart/alternative` email.

Answer (score 0):

From the file extension of your email template (`.text.erb`) you can see that you are sending a plain text email, that is why the link tag shows up in its raw form in the mail client. You should just send the plain URL in the plain text version of your email:

```
# users_mailer/registration_confirmation.text.erb

<%= @user.name %>
Thank you for registering!
To edit your password, please visit the following URL:

 <%= users_resetpass_url( :host => "localhost:3000") %>
```

You can provide both a plain text and a html version of your email by using the `.html.erb` extension for the second template:

```
# users_mailer/registration_confirmation.html.erb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><%= @user.name %></p>
    <p>Thank you for registering!</p>
    <p>Edit Your Password <%= link_to "Click Here",users_resetpass_url( :host => "localhost:3000") %></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#walkthrough-to-generating-a-mailer